# How mobile session is defined in Google Analytics

Tags: session, mobile, google-analytics, analytics

I need to know how **mobile** session is defined in google analytics. But I can't get any informations from google. 
I found [this](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2731565?hl=en) article from google but It doesn't apply for mobile environments at all. Can't anyone explain me or give me some articles about this? Thank a lots!

Comment: I am the QA Lead Engineer for a mobile development company and the Technical Google Analytics Subject Matter Expert there, so I've had a lot of time to use this service. I had the same problem you did, but we eventually got it figured out. I answered this here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42961255/6153284

Answer (score 0):

Mobile sessions are those that come from a Google maintained list of user-agents that are from mobile devices, such as iPhone etc.

If you are asking about how sessions are defined per time, then GA for mobile will be similar to page tracking in that it will be as per your sessions settings in the admin interface: by default this is that if a user doesn't register a new hit within 30 mins, their session ends; or a new session begins if the campaign source changes e.g. if a user arrives via Google and then 29 minutes later by Yahoo, they will register as two sessions.

Hope it helps.