# session duration more than the default (30 minutes) in google analytics

Tags: session, google-analytics

In my google analytics the session time is set to 30 minutes.
but the avg. session duration that I see in my report tables is more than 30 minutes in some cases. How can it be possible?I am so confused.please please help me.

thanks a million 
Regards

Comment: That means that 30 min of inactivity will end your sessions. If The user did not make any pause the sessions can be long as the user navigates

Answer (score 0):

## Main Points

- This is possible because each time there is activity (event or screen view) in your app, the
  session timeout timer is reset to the full duration.
- *Inactive* time in the app **is counted**, but only under specific 
  conditions
- Understanding how Google defines when an app is *inactive* really helps

### In-Depth

*Inactivity* is any period in the app session when the user is not interacting with it, **and** the session timeout has not yet been met. *It does not matter if the app is backgrounded or foregrounded while the user is inactive.* In other words, If you have the app backgrounded, or are simply sitting idle on an app page, **you would be considered inactive in both scenarios**.

Session Timeout *is not actually a setting, but rather a **variable*** that is used to calculate the session length.

```
session timer = 0 minutes

user launches app (session timer starts)

while countdown is not 0 (starting from timeout setting)

   if user triggered event OR viewed screen
      add inactivity time to session time
      restart countdown
   else
      continue with countdown
```

Pardon the crudely-written pseudocode, but the point is, time spent in background is only counted if there is some activity in the app that occurs before the session timeout is met.

Unfortunately, I don't have any documentation to support this (as it doesn't exist, which is why I am taking the time to write this). However, I have tested this on both iOS and Android using the official Google Analytics SDK and this is indeed how it works. I can discuss the test with you if need be.